# python scipy.minimize, constrain by value calculated in objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I'm using scipy.minimize for optimizing with constraints. The function calculates a vector of rates in a linear chain of reactions given some system-wide parameters and looks something like

```
def getRates(x,params):
    param1 = params['thing1']  # np arrays that are set prior to optimizing
    param2 = params['thing2']
    rates = x * param1 / param2 # rates are nx1 vector
    return 1/rates.min()        # optimizing for 1/min rates to find maximum minimum rate
```

I have seen how constraints and bounds can be set for x, and

```
minimize(getRates,x0,args=pars,),method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,bounds=bnds)
```

seems to be respecting them. However, I would like to constrain the rates that are calculated in to be equal to each other - this is meant to model a linear chain of reactions. Is it possible to do this with the minimize function?

Many thanks